# How to draw a circle each point of polygon and fill the point with different color?

Tags: html, canvas

I have a polygon with an array of coordinates , but i want to draw a point in each coordinates such as circle and fill the point with different color of poylgon

I try to fill the circle but i think it's not right

```
    const drawPolygon = () => {
        context.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch)
        context.beginPath()
        context.moveTo(coordinates[0].x, coordinates[0].y)
        coordinates.forEach((item) => {
            context.lineTo(item.x, item.y)
            context.arc(item.x, item.y, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
        })
        context.closePath()
        context.stroke()
        context.fill()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to vary your fill colors, you'll need to call `stroke()` and `fill()` again for every new shape.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
const cw = canvas.width
const ch = canvas.height
const coordinates = [{x:20,y:20}, {x:270,y:40}, {x:230,y:130} , {x:50,y:90}]

const drawPolygon = () => {
  context.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch)
  
  // Draw polygon
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,.3)'
  context.beginPath()
  coordinates.forEach((item) => {
    context.lineTo(item.x, item.y)
  })
  context.closePath()
  context.stroke()
  context.fill()
  
  // Draw coordinate circles
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,255,.3)'
  coordinates.forEach((item) => {
    context.beginPath()
    context.arc(item.x, item.y, 13, 0, Math.PI * 2, true)
    context.stroke()
    context.fill()
  })
}

drawPolygon()
document.body.appendChild(canvas)
```

Comment: I find the solution it's look like your code . It's working , it's my wrong . thanks for your help